# Is there a Python function for creating a desktop shortcut?

Tags: python

I just made a little Python project, then used PyInstaller to convert it to a .exe.  I want to create a shortcut to the desktop when the user downloads it from an HTML page I made. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to go about this is to set up a windows installer for your python program. This installer can also be made in python, by the way, this method is fairly unorthodox since you would not make windows style apps with python.

https://python101.pythonlibrary.org/chapter44_creating_an_installer.html

I recommend you take a look at the link above, it gives a good guide on creating an installer for your program as well as how to package it properly.

Hope it Helps :)